# How to get "Adobe Subject Matter Expert - Adobe Commerce Architect" Badge?

Tags: magento2, certification

Does anyone know how to get this badge - https://www.credly.com/org/adobe/badge/adobe-subject-matter-expert-adobe-commerce-architect

It says:

Earning Criteria

> Become an Adobe SME Community member, Participate in one or more Adobe
> certification exam workshops or curriculum development projects

But looking for the steps to do that. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply when you receive an invite for volunteering opportunity.

For Adobe, it is preferred that SMEs are Adobe Commerce certified or have equivalent or higher credentials.

You have to be selected by Adobe after you apply and accept your profile.

Once approved, you receive details of workshops that you will attend in order to contribute in the construction of the exam (you also must sign an NDA) .

Once all workshops are done you get the Subject matter expert badge.

Comment: > you receive an invite for volunteering opportunity.
Hi, how to get this invite?

Answer (score 0):

The above are instructions for participating in creation of the exam.

To take the exam and get certified just sign up through Adobe

https://solutionpartners.adobe.com/solution-partners/training_and_certification/certification.html#certification_exams

Commerce Archticct Guide
https://express.adobe.com/page/5CMBLo1UK4xxv/